# Cordova system browser apk link does not open

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, inappbrowser

I am using the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open a link in the system browser like so:

```js
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://example.com/myapp.apk', '_system');
```

This works if the browser is not running already when this line is executed. It also worked with all other but my apk links that I tried.

If the browser is already running however, the tab immediately vanishes again without starting the download. Is this a bug in the inappbrowser plugin or chrome mobile? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The almighty setTimeout solved this problem (I have no idea why, would be happy if someone could explain):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://example.com/myapp.apk', '_system');
}, 250);
```

Comment: Probably cordova.js wasn't loaded before you called the inAppbrowser functions

Comment: have you wrapped the function in a deviceready event listener? `document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
  cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://example.com/myapp.apk', '_system');
}`